# How to use sitemap_generator with paperclip upload to s3 in heroku

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I know sitemap_generator use CarrierWave to upload to s3. Can it support paperclip? If yes, Can anyone tell me how to upload sitemap files (generated by sitemap_generator in heroku) to s3 using paperclip?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a rake file to handle all that without loosing any of the current behavior of the gem, all you have to do is to download the code I created:

https://gist.github.com/1693860